# How to populate a data layer with an existing database from MySQL Workbench?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mysql-workbench

I am creating an MVVM WPF app and I have a problem trying to populate my data layer from the schema in MySQL Workbench.I tried to add an ADO.NET data model connected to an existing database with EF Designer,but when I want to populate it ,I get only 2 options which consists in Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SQL Server Database File although I need MySQL Database.I tried "other" and wrote the data source manually but then I got an error saying that the server was not found or doesn't support remote connections.There is another way to do this or how should I manage to pull this off?This is my first time when I'm trying to populate my data layer from the database so any detail will be appreciated.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the latest version of MySQL Installer which includes MySQL for Visual Studio 2017 with a connector as per their [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html).